# I am able to hit the API even after the token expires

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

```
public SecurityToken GenerateJwt(ApiInfo? apiInfo, AccountModel.AccountDetails input)
    {

        var authClaims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, input.Name), new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), };

        //foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
        //{
        //    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
        //}


        var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("JWT:SecretKey").Value));
        //var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT: SecretKey"]));

        //var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        //issuer: _configuration.GetSection("JWT:ValidIssuer").Value,
        //audience: _configuration.GetSection("JWT:ValidAudience").Value,
        //expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
        //claims: authClaims,
        //signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        //);

        //
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        //var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(authClaims),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return token;
    }
```

Above code generates the token

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using RestaurantApp.Core.Entities;
using RestaurantApp.Core.Helpers;
using RestaurantApp.Service.Infrastructure;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI;
using System.Text;
using WonApi.Service.Infrastructure;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Start ------------------------------------------------
ConfigureApp(builder);
//builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenAuthHandler>();
//builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer");
//builder.Services.AddAuthorization(o =>
//{
//    o.AddPolicy(AppConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_BASED_AUTHORIZATION_POLICY, policy =>
//    {
//        policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenBasedAuthRequirement());
//    });
//});
// End --------------------------------------------------

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
    {
        //o.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
{
    // UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds replacement for .NET Core
    // o.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);

    // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
    o.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"Restaurant.Web.xml"));
    //o.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"Restaurant.Core.xml"));
    //o.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"Restaurant.BO.xml"));
});


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.SaveToken = true;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ValidAudience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment() || app.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(o =>
    {
        // o.RoutePrefix = "help";
        o.DefaultModelExpandDepth(-1);
        o.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
    });
}


//app.UseAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(o =>
//{
//    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
//    o.SaveToken = true;
//    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
//    {
//        ValidateIssuer = true,
//        ValidateAudience = true,
//        ValidateLifetime = true,
//        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
//        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
//        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
//        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
//    };
//});


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


static void ConfigureApp(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddCors(o =>
    {
        o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", b => b.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        //o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", b => b.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        //o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", b => b.WithOrigins("https://won.azurewebsites.net", "http://localhost","http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

        //o.AddPolicy(name: "AllowedCorsOrigins",
        //      builder =>
        //      {
        //          builder
        //              .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => { return new Uri(origin).Host.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || new Uri(origin).Host.Equals("won.azurewebsites.net", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); })
        //              .AllowAnyHeader()
        //              .AllowAnyMethod()
        //              .AllowCredentials();
        //      });

    });
    AppSettings_Load(builder);
    AppLoader.SysConfig_Read(null);

    //builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    // .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    // {
    //     options.Authority = $"https://{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";
    //     options.TokenValidationParameters =
    //       new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    //       {
    //           ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"],
    //           ValidIssuer = $"{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}"
    //       };
    // });



    builder.Services.RegisterServices();
    builder.Services.RegisterRepositories();


    LogHelper.CreateInstance();
}

static void AppSettings_Load(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    // load ConnectionStrings
    var section_1 = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
    AppSettings.ConnectionStrings.RestaurantAppDb = DataHelper.ParseToString(section_1["WonDb"]);

    // load AppConfig
    var section_2 = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig");
    AppSettings.AppConfig.QueryTimeoutSeconds = DataHelper.ParseToInt(section_2["QueryTimeoutSeconds"], 30);
    AppSettings.AppConfig.ThrowException = DataHelper.ParseToBoolean(section_2["ThrowException"], false);
    AppSettings.AppConfig.ClientKey = DataHelper.ParseToString(section_2["ClientKey"]);
    AppSettings.AppConfig.ReUseTenantAccessToken = DataHelper.ParseToBoolean(section_2["ReUseTenantAccessToken"], false);
}
```

Above is the entire code in program.cs

My problem is that even after the token expires I am able to hit the API

Code for the API is as follows

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ReatuarnatAppService;
using RestaurantApp.Core.Entities;
using RestaurantAppBO.Entities;

namespace RestaurantApp.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/restaurant")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class FoodDrinkController : BaseController
    {
        IFoodDrinkService _service;

        public FoodDrinkController(IFoodDrinkService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }



        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("get-all-food-items")]
        public IActionResult GetAllFoodItems()
        {
            ApiInfo? apiInfo = null;
            try
            {
                apiInfo = ApiInfo.Create(HttpContext);

                var result = _service.GetAllFoodItems(apiInfo);

                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return this.HandleException(apiInfo, ex);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

My code is in asp.net core. I am able to hit the API even after the token expires

Comment: Hi @Slow Death, did you mean you want to increase the token expired time or use the refresh token to make the api accessible again? Because If api can be accessed when the token is expired, why you authorize it originally?

Comment: @Rena I want the api to be accessed if the token hasnot expired. If the token expires I want the API to return 401

Comment: Hi @Slow Death, oh my misunderstanding. So when you configure `Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),` here, the api still works after one minutes, right?

Comment: Besides,`ValidateIssuer` and `ValidateAudience` are set true, but you do not configure `Issuer` and `Audience` option value which is in `SecurityTokenDescriptor`, it can work? It suppose to be 401 if you do not configure them.

Comment: Eventhoughj i have not configured ValidateIssuer and ValidateAudience in SecurityTokenDescriptor my api still works.
Do you want me to put ValidateIssuer and ValidateAudience  in the SecurityTokenDescriptor

Comment: Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), yes ,the api still works after one minutes,

Comment: Someone please help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252286/discussion-between-slow-death-and-rena).

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.SaveToken = true;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ValidAudience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    };
    o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
        {
            c.NoResult();
            c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            c.Response.WriteAsync(c.Exception.ToString()).Wait();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnChallenge = c =>
        {
            c.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
})
```

The JwtBearerEvents catches the AuthenticationFailed case and from here we can return an appropriate response.

If you dont catch the AuthenticationFailed  event here the request is passed to the API

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).